# The input value codes refused to work in react js

Tags: reactjs

What could be wrong with these codes? The input is not working once I add [event.target.name]. If I remove that line of codes, I can see the contents that I type inside the input box. The issue is that I want it to work with this code [event.target.name]. This will enable me pick each inputbox values as entered by the user. There are three input boxes and I need to capture the three values in my useState. Any help on how to write it better?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "./addbirthday.css";
import "./home.css";


export default function Addbirthday({setShowAdd}) {

const [inputDatas, setInputData] = useState([
    {fullName: '', fullDate: '', relationship: ''}
]);

 const handlePublish = () =>{
     console.log("Hi ", inputDatas)
}

const handleChangeInput = (index, event) =>{
    const values = [...inputDatas];
    values[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value
    setInputData(values)       
}


 return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className= { closeInput? "addContainer" :"addWrapper homeWrapper  "}>
            <i className="fas fa-window-close" onClick={closeNow} ></i>
                
                {inputDatas.map((inputData, index)=> (
                    <div key={index} className="addbirth">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Fname" placeholder='Namend' value= 
    {inputData.fullName} onChange = {event => handleChangeInput(index, event)} />
                        
                        <label>Date</label>
                        <input type="date" placeholder='Date' name="fdate" value= 
     {inputData.fullDate} onChange = {event => handleChangeInput(index, event)} />
                        <label>Relationship</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder='Friend' name="frelationship" value= 
      {inputData.relationship} onChange = {event => handleChangeInput(index, event)}/>
                    </div>
                    
                ))}
           
            <button className="addBtn" onClick={handlePublish} >Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the name correctly

Change your input tags name to same as state object name meaning

`<input name='fullname' />`

I have modified your code a bit. Make it as your own and get it done.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-khayyam-51ybe?file=/src/App.js:0-1711

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Addbirthday({ setShowAdd }) {
  const [inputDatas, setInputData] = useState([
    { Fname: "", fdate: "", frelationship: "" }
  ]);

  const handlePublish = () => {
    console.log("Hi ", inputDatas);
  };

  const handleChangeInput = (index, event) => {
    const values = [...inputDatas];
    values[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setInputData(values);
    console.log(values[index][event.target.name]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className={"addContainer addWrapper homeWrapper"}>
        <i className="fas fa-window-close"></i>

        {inputDatas.map((inputData, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="addbirth">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="Fname"
              placeholder="Namend"
              value={inputData.fullName}
              onChange={(event) => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
            />

            <label>Date</label>
            <input
              type="date"
              placeholder="Date"
              name="fdate"
              value={inputData.fullDate}
              onChange={(event) => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
            />
            <label>Relationship</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Friend"
              name="frelationship"
              value={inputData.relationship}
              onChange={(event) => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}

        <button className="addBtn" onClick={handlePublish}>
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```